# How to prepend route with /blog for blog listing page only

Tags: url-rewriting

My permalink settings is simply `/%postname%/` (yes I read from the codex that this is bad performance practice). The result is:

- a page url might look like `site.com/pagename`
- a blog post looks like `site.com/post-title`
- a portfolio (custom post type) post will look like `site.com/portfolio/item-1`

I would like my blog post page (`single.php`) to have a URL like `site.com/blog/post-title`. How might I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your permalink structure to `/blog/%postname%/`.

### EDIT

To get your custom post type to leave out the `/blog` part, in its registration arguments array, set the rewrite argument like this:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false )
```

Comment: It won't "fail", those CPTs will just have 'blog' at the beginning of their permastruct. That's totally expected behavior. You could also filter those post types' rewrite rules on the `'{$post_type}_rewrite_rules'` filter, removing '/blog' from the beginning of any rule regexes.